# Akari: The Light

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Rules (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/akari.html)):**
>
> 1. Place light bulbs (circles) according to the following rules.
> 2. Light bulbs may be placed in any of the white squares, the number in the square shows how many light bulbs are next to it, vertically and horizontally.
> 3. Each light bulb illuminates from bulb to black square or outer frame in its row and column.
> 4. Every white square must be illuminated and a light bulb can not illuminate another light bulb.

Comment: Does an empty black square mean that any number of light bulbs may be next to it?

Comment: @WeatherVane that's correct, empty black square may adjacent to any number of light bulbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First fill in the obvious ones

> [image]

Continue as follows

> [image]

Continue

> [image]

Continue by identifying where bulbs can't be

> [image]

Continue

> [image]

And Finally

> [image]

Comment: Yep, this is correct, well done! :D