# Akari: Another Light

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Rules (taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/akari.html)):**
>
> 1. Place light bulbs (circles) according to the following rules.
> 2. Light bulbs may be placed in any of the white squares, the number in the square shows how many light bulbs are next to it, vertically and horizontally.
> 3. Each light bulb illuminates from bulb to black square or outer frame in its row and column.
> 4. Every white square must be illuminated and a light bulb can not illuminate another light bulb.

---

<sup>Adding note for avoiding the duplicate error with [Akari: The Light](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95237/28719).</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final solution

> [image: final solution]

### Step by step deduction

Some "easy" deductions (no lights around 0, lights in white squares surrounded by black, etc.) get us to here:

> [image: first steps]

See that 1 in the fourth row, third column? I'm going to assume the light next to it is on the right, and then we can deduce as follows to get a contradiction:

> [image: first contradiction]

In fact, that same contradiction would arise just from saying there is no light between the two 1s in the ninth row (then there must be a light below the left one, to the right of the right one, and around the 2 below that). So we have:

> [image: next steps]

Now in the right-hand column, the square just above the bottom 1 can only be lit from one possible place. From there we get lots more deductions, finishing off the bottom half of the board:

> [image: almost done]

See those two 1s almost next to each other near the top of the eighth column? If they have no light between them, then we get a contradiction as follows:

> [image: second contradiction]

So they must have a light between them, and we finish off the board as follows:

> [image: final solution]

Comment: Just pwned me :P

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as this provides explanations despite it's beaten by several minutes. Great job and +1 for both of you :)

Answer (score 5):

**Here is the solution:**

> (Red means light bulb, yellow means light)
>
>  [image: Akari Puzzle: Solution]

Comment: Beat me by some minutes :-) +1